# In PyCharm I am setting breakpoints but it doesn't seem to stop at any of them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have changed some code and can confirm the line I change causes the app to display different text.

However when I set a breakpoint on that line like this then it never stops at the breakpoint.

Here's what I am seeing in the console. It seems there are problems when it tries to attach the debugger:

```
Attaching to a process with PID=47102
/bin/bash "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_pydevd.py" --port 65032 --pid 47102
from: can't read /var/mail/__future__
/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_pydevd.py: line 2: import: command not found
/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_pydevd.py: line 3: import: command not found
/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_pydevd.py: line 4: import: command not found
/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_pydevd.py: line 5: import: command not found
/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_pydevd.py: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_pydevd.py: line 8: `def process_command_line(argv):'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Then when I look at that file it looks like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import traceback


def process_command_line(argv):
    setup = {}
    setup['port'] = 5678  # Default port for PyDev remote debugger
    setup['pid'] = 0
    setup['host'] = '127.0.0.1'
    setup['protocol'] = ''

    i = 0
    while i < len(argv):
        if argv[i] == '--port':
            del argv[i]
            setup['port'] = int(argv[i])
            del argv[i]

        elif argv[i] == '--pid':
            del argv[i]
            setup['pid'] = int(argv[i])
            del argv[i]

        elif argv[i] == '--host':
            del argv[i]
            setup['host'] = argv[i]
            del argv[i]

        elif argv[i] == '--protocol':
            del argv[i]
            setup['protocol'] = argv[i]
            del argv[i]

    if not setup['pid']:
        sys.stderr.write('Expected --pid to be passed.\n')
        sys.exit(1)
    return setup
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be wrong?

Comment: That's a big pile of shell error messages. You seem to be running your Python file as a shell script. Recheck the command line used to run your file.

Comment: Actually, it's the debugger attacher thingy that's getting run as a shell script - see the `/bin/bash` in `/bin/bash "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_pydevd.py" --port 65032 --pid 47102`. Try to recall anything weird you might have done to cause that.

Comment: That happens when I do Run > Attach to Attach to Process.  When I instead click the Debug then nothing really happens and the debug window doesn't open.